# How to save the order of objects created dynamically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, stimulusjs

I'm using Rails and Stimulus JS to allow a user to add multiple Guardians for their child to the database. A child has_many guardians. A Guardian has a name attribute. A user can add up to 3 total guardians for a child and can also remove guardians, so the number of guardians on the page is not static. The order of the Guardians is important, because the first Guardian on the page is the "Primary" Guardian and the next two are "Backup" Guardians.

What's the best way to save the order of the elements to the database in a "guardian_position" attribute for each Guardian object? For example, the first guardian on the screen needs to have a guardian_position of "1", the second should have a guardian_position of "2", etc. I know I can use a hidden field and set the value dynamically based on the position of the element on the screen, but that seems kind of hacky and the user can manipulate it if they want to.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why can’t you add an attribute on the guardian table and sort by that?

Comment: @hashrocket but how do I set the attribute is the question, given that these guardians are added dynamically by the user and there is no input to set the guardian_position. The one on top is the primary guardian, then if they add another Guardian beneath it that is the first backup Guardian, etc.

Comment: You would have to add a field in the form for the position. You can use an enum so the form uses words instead of numbers. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html